# Handling QListWidget clicking and scrolling

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I have a QListWidget with some items (QListWidgetItem's). Of course, the items have their own controls like buttons, lineedits and so on...

For my QListWidget I set in constructor:

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);
this->grabGesture(Qt::TapGesture, Qt::IgnoredGesturesPropagateToParent | Qt::ReceivePartialGestures);
```

Essentially the problem is my event handling:

```
bool ListControl::event(QEvent* e)
{
    auto event = e->type();
    if (event == QEvent::TouchBegin)
    {
        auto touch = dynamic_cast<QTouchEvent*>(e);
        if (touch)
        {
            return this->HandleTouch(touch, event);
        }
    }

    ...some code comes here...

    return QListWidget::event(e);
}
```

When I return on **QEvent::TouchBegin** the **HandleTouch**-Method, then I can move the list of elements (QListWidgetItems). With "move" I mean scrolling the list, with my finger on the mobile phone-touch screen. But then I can't get focus on any control of any QListWidgetItem.

When I return on **QEvent::TouchBegin** QListWidget::event(e), then I get focus on the controls, but I can no more scroll the list.

I tried a lot, but nothing helped. How could I solve this problem, to move/scroll the list with my finger, but also can get focus to the controls, on taping on it.

*Supplement*:
I measure the tap-duration. If it was less than 150ms, then I get the QWidget that was clicked.
Only I do not manage to send the widget a message, so that it reacts.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got a solution! Quick and dirty explained... the trick is in the touch handler (QEvent::TouchBegin), you must set the focus, to the taped widget.
If the widget is for example a QPushButton, you must return false, otherwise true. These solution works for me!

```
const auto posf = event->touchPoints().first().pos();
QPoint position(posf.x(), posf.y());

auto widget = this->childAt(position);
if (widget)
{
    widget->setFocus();
    widget->activateWindow();
    widget->raise();
}

auto button = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(widget);
result = (button == nullptr);
```

Maybe I can help someone